# Change the value of a key in ES6 constructor

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, ecmascript-6

**Question:**
How do I write a proper prototypical function using classes in ES6?  How do I make sure that this function will change the value of title key in the constructor of Todo class?

```
class Todo{
    constructor(title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    setTitle(newTitle){
        this.title = newTitle;
    }

}
var a1 = new Todo('gym');
console.log(a1);
a1.setTitle = 'Work';
console.log(a1);
```

**The console logs log out this**

`LOG: Todo{title: 'gym', list: List{title: 'empty'}}`

`LOG: Todo{title: 'gym', list: List{title: 'empty'}, setTitle: 'Work'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTitle` is a function, so you need to call it, not assign to it.

```
var a1 = new Todo('gym');
console.log(a1);
a1.setTitle('Work');
console.log(a1);
```